# How to convert SHAP Values into Probabilities?

Tags: python, shap

I am using the Shap library in Python to explain my model that I used Catboost for. When attempting to use several plots, I use these commands:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values, X_train)
shap.dependence_plot("some feature", shap_values, X_train)
```

The output of each gives me Shap-Values on the x-axis, however I am not able to interpret it and think its easier to use probabilities. How would I be able to do that?

I read that for Catboost one cannot use: `explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model,data = X,model_output='probability')`

Thus, I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can consider is using the log link on the force_plot, this is shown in [the shap vignette](https://github.com/slundberg/shap#model-agnostic-example-with-kernelexplainer-explains-any-function), for example:

```
import shap
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
shap.initjs()

X,y = shap.datasets.iris()
y = np.where(y==1,1,0)

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool

model = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=False)
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model.predict_proba, X_train, link="logit")
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test, nsamples=10)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[2], shap_values[2], X_test, link="logit")
```

[image]

From this you can across all samples, how each feature contribute towards the final probability

Comment: Thanks! How would I do that for the other two plots? I tried adding link function but that does not go for those. Any idea?

Comment: you can't do it for the other two plots.. it doesn't work that way